# How to resolve "Unexpected token" error while running npm install?

Tags: npm, deck.gl

I am trying to set up my project by running `npm install`, but encountered the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@loaders.gl/core/node_modules/@probe.gl/log/dist/utils/hi-res-timestamp.js 7:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     let timestamp;
|     if (isBrowser() && window.performance) {
>         timestamp = window?.performance?.now?.();
|     }
|     else if ('hrtime' in process) {
 @ ./node_modules/@loaders.gl/core/node_modules/@probe.gl/log/dist/index.js 12:0-64 12:0-64
 @ ./node_modules/@loaders.gl/core/dist/esm/lib/utils/log.js
 @ ./node_modules/@loaders.gl/core/dist/esm/lib/api/select-loader.js
 @ ./node_modules/@loaders.gl/core/dist/esm/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@deck.gl/core/dist/esm/lib/init.js
 @ ./node_modules/@deck.gl/core/dist/esm/index.js
 @ ./icon-cluster-layer.js
 @ ./app.js
```

How can I resolve this issue and successfully run `npm install`?

I have already tried clearing the npm cache and reinstalling the dependencies, but the error persists. Any guidance on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!